# How can one specify exact retention for Graphite query

Tags: graphite

Say we have some schema like this

```
retentions = 15s:7d,1m:21d,15m:5y
```

How can I query data with specified retention. For example I want to get data only for one last day but with 1 minute sampling rate;

Thank you.

P.S. I'm using Graphite as a [render api](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html) client. Can't find anything usefull by now. Is it possible to do this with default api. Or whether this opportunity can be realized with server side configuration or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The accurate way to get data directly out from Graphite without using 'summarize', which may carry out calculations is the following, of course that is if your team is familiar with Perl.

1. Download the Whisper.pm CPAN module.
2. Modify the function "sub wsp_fetch" as follows:
   2.1 Send a new parameter to the %param hash, such that this parameter specifies "which retention to use".
   2.2 Now, insert few lines of code (not more than 10 lines), which will: (a) Find out available retentions, and then (b) Fetch the data from the specified retention if it exists.

I hope this helps. As I said, this is the most reliable to fetch retention-based data directly out from Graphite in the absence of any functions or third party tool to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Found. As I understand it can be handled with [summarize](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) function.